# How to extract direct HTML data into VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, web-scraping

```
<div class="r_title">
    <h1 data-securitycontent="name">Fidelity® Japan Smaller Companies</h1>
    <span class="gry">&nbsp;FJSCX</span>
    <span data-msat="span-securityInformation-star" class="r_star3"></span>
```

How would I go about extracting r_star3 from this? r_star3 represents 3 stars.  So far, I'm able to get the inner text of it, but the stars are symbols so its blank and r_star3 seems to be its own class. I'd like to just extract r_star3 as a string and use if statements to see how many stars it is. Anything helps, thanks.

Edit:

Here's what I have so far using query selector, but the querySelector prints out [object HTMLSpanElement]. I only pasted in the relevant code. [This](http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/vsmpx/quote.html) is the site where the stars are located (right by the ticker signs).

```
    .navigate "http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/" & Range("A" & Row.Row).Value & "/quote.html"
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document
    While ie.readyState <> 4
    Wend

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))

    Dim tblName As Object
    Dim span As Object

    On Error Resume Next





    'FIND THE STAR (Work in Progress)
    Set tblName = doc.getElementsByClassName("reports_nav")(0)
    Set span = tblName.getElementsByTagName("span").Item(1)


    Dim s As String, rating As Long
    s = doc.querySelector("span[class*=""r_star""]")
    MsgBox (s)

    rating = Replace(Split(Split(s, "class=" & Chr$(34))(1), Chr$(34))(0), "r_star", vbNullString)
    Range("C" & Row.Row).Value = rating
    MsgBox (rating)
```

Comment: The functions you're looking for are in the `VBA.Strings` module. Type `VBA.Strings.` and let IntelliSense guide your coding: you'll see functions like `Left`, `Right`, and `Mid`, among others. The *Object Browser* (F2) lets you explore the modules of every type library referenced by your VBA project - including the VBA standard library and the host application's object model :-)

Comment: That said I believe I'd expect the `r_star3` string to be in the element's `class` property if there's such a thing (not familiar with this API), otherwise I'd find a way to get the element's `attributes` and find the `class` attribute and grab its value. I think the `innerText` would be `<tag>inner text</tag>`.

Comment: Is there an URL to go with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain target HTML with CSS selector e.g. the following will get the element in question:

```
span[data-msat="span-securityInformation-star"]
```

which returns:

[image: CSS query]

---

**Parse result:**

You can then parse the OuterHTML from the returned element to get the start rating.

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Get_Information()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/seatx/quote.html"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim a As Object, exitTime As Date
        exitTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set a = .document.querySelector("span[data-msat=""span-securityInformation-star""]")   '<== Loop until time out checking if element has been found and set
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Now > exitTime Then Exit Do
        Loop While a Is Nothing

        If a Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        Dim rating As Long
        rating = Replace(Split(Split(a.outerHTML, "class=" & Chr$(34))(1), Chr$(34))(0), "r_star", vbNullString)

        MsgBox rating

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help; I'm still having a little trouble getting span and the querySelector to cooperate. When I test, the querySelector is returning [object HTMLSpanElement] which in turn sets the rating to 0. Is this due to me not declaring Span correctly? Thank you!

Comment: Here is an example of a URL I would use, the stars are right by the ticker symbol: http://www.morningstar.com/funds/xnas/seatx/quote.html